# Post photo in facebook on the friends gallery for ios

Tags: ios, facebook, gallery

Good morning,

I have this code to post a photo in my gallery:

```
- (IBAction)postPhotoClick:(UIButton *)sender {
    // Just use the icon image from the application itself.  A real app would have a more
    // useful way to get an image.
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon-72@2x.png"];

    // if it is available to us, we will post using the native dialog
    BOOL displayedNativeDialog = [FBNativeDialogs presentShareDialogModallyFrom:self
                                                                    initialText:nil
                                                                          image:img
                                                                            url:nil
                                                                        handler:nil];
    if (!displayedNativeDialog) {
        [self performPublishAction:^{

            [FBRequestConnection startForUploadPhoto:img
                                   completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                                       [self showAlert:@"Photo Post" result:result error:error];
                                       self.buttonPostPhoto.enabled = YES;
                                   }];

            self.buttonPostPhoto.enabled = NO;
            //proceedToPost();
        }];
    }
}
```

However, I need to post the photo in my friends' gallery. It's possible? How can I do such?

Comment: hey man, thanks for sharing this! can you post the full post-to-gallery code? im quite a newbie at this and it would be very helpful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution, by using the graphs API.

After doing the appropriate login:

```
 NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   self.originalImage, @"source", 
                                   @"MessageText", @"message",
                                   nil];

 [self.facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"user_name/photos/"
                              andParams:params
                              andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                              andDelegate:self];
```

This code works to post an image in my albuns. Now I need to post a photo on my friends' albums.